# CSS / CGRect Positioning

Tags: javascript, ios, css, xcode, cgrect

#### CSS

I have a database with a table plan, each table has a property of `geometry`, with the `x` and `y` values.
These values when presented in a web browser get rendered like so:

```
getStyles() {
   const { x, y } = this.props.geometry || {};
   return {
      left: `${x}%`,
      top: `${y}%`,
   };
}
```

So obviously the `x` and `y` are percentage values out of 100.

#### iOS

I've created a `UIScrollView` and a subclass for the view of each table (`TableView`).
When the view is added to the scrollView, a method inside `TableView` gets called to update the table position which looks like this:

```c
- (void)updateTablePosition:(Table *)table {
    if (self.superview) {
        float x_position    =   (self.superview.frame.size.width / 100) * table.position.x;
        float y_position    =   (self.superview.frame.size.height / 100) * table.position.y;
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(x_position, y_position, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

The positions are perfect! However, I have a pan gesture for each `TableView` which allows me to move them and change the position, the only problem is I can't figure out how to translate this value back to what it would be in CSS (a percentage).

Edit: Removed code to change position because it was completely wrong.

```c
- (void)tablePanAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    UIScrollView *scrollView        =   (UIScrollView *)self.superview;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    }

    CGPoint updatedLocation         =   [sender locationInView:scrollView];
    self.center                     =   updatedLocation;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        // from here, we should convert the updated location
        // back to a relative percentage of the scrollView

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

And it turns out.. the answer was ridiculously simple, just took a little bit of thinking. Anyway, i'm answering this question just in case anyones not completely clued up on maths.

The new `Table`.`geometry` positions can be calculated like so:

```c
float new_css_x   =   (self.frame.origin.x / scrollView.frame.size.width) * 100;
float new_css_y   =   (self.frame.origin.y / scrollView.frame.size.height) * 100;
```